# Given an integer array (of size N) and a number M, find product of N-1 elements of the array modulo M

Tags: algorithm

Let's say you are given an array `A` of `N` integers and another integer `M`. For any given index `i` where `0 <= i < N`, hide the `ith` index of `A` and return the product of all other elements of A modulo M.

For example, say `A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` and `M=100` then for `i=1`, the result would be `(1x3x4x5) mod 100`. Hence the result is 60.

Assume that all integers are 32 bit unsigned integers.

Now an obvious approach to do this is to calculate the result for any given value of `i`. That would mean `N-1` multiplications for every given value of `i`. Is there a more optimal way to do this?

P.S. 
First idea would be to store the product of all numbers in `A` (let's call this `total`). Now for every given value of `i`, we can just divide `total` by `A[i]` and return the result after taking the modulo. However, the `total` would cause an overflow so this cannot be done.

Comment: Why do you need to do this if we may ask?

Comment: check my answer..it works

Comment: @TimBIegeleisen : I was asked this in a coding interview where I used the basic approach but many of the test cases timed out. So I'm still wondering what would be the optimal approach to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Easy...:)

```
left[0]=a[0];
for(int i=1;i<=n-1;i++)
    left[i]=(left[i-1]*a[i])%M;

right[n-1]=a[n-1];
for(int i=n-2;i>=0;i--)
    right[i]=(right[i-1]*a[i])%M;


for query q
    if(q==0)
        return right[1]%M;
    if(q==n-1)
        return left[n-2]%M;
    return (left[q-1]*right[q+1])%M;
```

Suppose there is an array of 5 elements.
Now

```
index:   1  2  3  4  5
         1  5  2  10 4
```

Now for query q=3

```
answer is = ((1*5) * (10*4))%M
```

for query q=4

```
answer is = ((1*5*2)*(4))%M
```

We are basically pre computing all the left and right multiplication

```
index:   1      2      3    4    5
         1      5      2    10   4
 left:   1      5      10   100  400
right:   400    400    80   40   4
```

---

```
For q=3 answer is left[2]*right[4]= (5*40)%M= 200%M
For q=4 answer is left[3]*right[5]= (10*4)%M= 40%M
```

Comment: Could you please explain the approach here for better understanding of the code.

Comment: @PraveshJain.: sure..let me modify the answer.

Comment: Nice approach. @FDavidov also suggested an approach slightly similar to this.
In the 2 arrays that you are creating, I think it would be better to store the values after taking modulo. This would avoid overflow.

Comment: Good answer! You can make it a little simpler by defining `left[k] = product(A[i] for i = 0..k-1) (mod M)` and `right[k] = product(A[i] for i=k+1...n) (mod M)`. It makes both arrays 1 larger. Then you don't need any special cases, and `query(k) = (left[k] * right[k]) % M`.

Comment: @PaulHankin.: I will edit it and ping you soon enough..thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For this answer, I'm assuming that this is not a ONE-TIME calculation, but it is something that can take place many times with different values of `i`.

First, define a non-volatile array to hold calculated products.

Then, whenever the function is invoked with a given pair of parameters (`M` and `i`):

1. Check in the array (of above) if the product was calculated,
2. If yes, simply use the stored value, calculate the MOD and return the result,
3. If not, calculate the product, store it, calculate the MOD and return the value.

This method spares you from having a (potentially long) initialization which might calculate products that would not be needed.

Comment: Thank you. That's certainly an optimisation. If I don't find any more optimised solution soon, I'll accept this.